# Tips on solving precalc equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need some hints on my uni homework. 
I'm sure I made a mistake somewhere, but I don't see it (I'm solving for x):

$$\frac{x+\frac{1}{y}}{\frac{2}{z}-x}=\frac{2-\frac{2z}{y}}{\frac{y}{z}-1}
\\Solution: x=\frac{3}{y+2z} $$

$$\frac{xy+1}{y}*\frac{z}{2-xz} = \frac{2y-2z}{y}*\frac{z}{y-z}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{xyz+z}{2y-xyz}=\frac{2yz-2z^2}{y^2-yz} | *(2y-xyz)\tag{2}$$
$$xyz+z=\frac{4yz-2xyz^2-4z^2+2xz^3}{y-z} | *(y-z)\tag{3}$$
$$xy^2z-xyz^2+yz-z^2=4yz-2xyz^2-4z^2+2xz^3\tag{4}$$
$$xy^2z+xyz^2-2xz^3=3yz-3z^2\tag{5}$$
$$x=\frac{3yz-3z^2}{y^2z+yz^2-z^3}\tag{6}$$
$$x=\frac{3(y-z)}{y^2+yz-z^2}\tag{7}$$

I know I can go on from there, but I plugged that into the calculator and got conflicting results with the given solution (using two random values for $y$ and $z$.

Any suggestions or comments on the latex markup are highly appreciated!

Comment: Right after your equation $(1)$ you can multiply both sides by $y/z$ and then the single factors of $y,z$ will get cancelled at that step. Also after you do that, use that $(2y-2z)/(y-z)=2$ for another cancel.

Comment: After you do what is in my last comment it's only a few steps (after "cross multiplying") to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation gives $(x+ \frac 1 y) (\frac yz - 1) = (\frac 2z - x) (2 - \frac {2z} y)$  by the cross-ratio thing.

$\frac{xy+1}y \frac {y-z}z = \frac {2+xz}z \frac{2(y-z)}y$  Reducing fractions.

$xy+1 = 2 (2-xz)$     eliminate common factors.

$xy + 1 = 4 - 2xz$

$x(y+2z) = 3$

$x = \frac 3{y+2z}$

So it certianly does give the right results.

You make life complicated for yourself, by not eliminating common factors after writing equation 1.  There are three common factors $y-z$, $y$, and $z$, this reduces equation $2$ to   $\frac{xy+1}{2-xz}=2$, which follows on from what i do at 'eliminate common factors' above.

The mistake, though is in equation 6, where the $2xz^3$ is carried from eqn 5 to $xz^3$ in eqn 6.  When the 2 is restored, the top and bottom are multiples of $y-z$, which gives the indicated result.